# Actionscript 3 - ESC making application to go out of fullscreen mode

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So, how do I make it so that so when I got my application at `StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN`, it wont make it `StageDisplayState.NORMAL` on pressing esc? like if I want to make an in-movie pop-up menu, which appears on esc that includes all the options like exit and fullscreen or not -settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making a web based swf then there is no way to stop the escape key from quitting full screen mode, because of the security problems associated with **not** being able to leave a full screen movie. However if you are making an AIR application then there might be some work arounds that I am unsure of.

[More in depth explanation](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=226558)